# Is $f(a_1 + p\mathbb{Z},a_2 + p^2 \mathbb{Z}, \ldots) = (0,pa_1 + p^2 \mathbb{Z},\ldots)$ surjective?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $p$ be prime and the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ where $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ modulo $p^n$.  Define a map $f : M\to M$ by $f(a_1 + p\mathbb{Z},a_2 + p^2 \mathbb{Z},a_3 + p^3 \mathbb{Z},\ldots) = (0,pa_1 + p^2 \mathbb{Z},pa_2 + p^3 \mathbb{Z},\ldots)$

The question:  Is the map $f$

```
(1) surjective,

(2) injective?
```

**Answer:**  The image of $f, f(M)=Mp$.  This implies that $f$ is a multiplication map by $p$ and so is injective.   However I am failing to verify whether it is surjective or not.

Comment: Is there anything that hits $(1,0,0,\cdots)$? Also this map isn't _just_ multiplication by $p$. It's a shift and then multiplication.

Comment: Thank you, I had not realized the shifting!  If I am to ask, are all multiplication maps of this module surjective?

Comment: Of any module? Or this one? Regardless, no. Note that in this module, multiplication by $p$ automatically gets mapped to $0$ in the first factor. So there is nothing that hits $(1,0,\cdots)$, so it is not surjective. Multiplication by $p$ is not even injective here for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @mariam Also note that $f(M)=pM$, but $f$ is *not* multiplication by $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map $f$ is not surjective, because any element in the image of $f$ has zero first component.

Checking injectivity requires a little bit of work.  $f$ is a group homomorphism, so let's check that the kernel of $f$ is zero.  Suppose $f(a_1 + p\mathbb{Z},a_2 + p^2 \mathbb{Z},a_3 + p^3 \mathbb{Z},\ldots) = (0,pa_1 + p^2 \mathbb{Z},pa_2 + p^3 \mathbb{Z},\ldots)$ is the zero vector.  So $pa_1\equiv 0\pmod{p^2}$.  Dividing by $p$ we see that $a_1$ is a multiple of $p$.  Similarly any $pa_i\equiv 0\pmod{p^{i+1}}$ and $a_i$ is a multiple of $p^i$.  So the initial vector $(a_1, a_2,...)$ is the zero element of $M$.